# App can only go through firewall if its turned off (cant add as an exception)

Tags: c#, windows-firewall

I made a simple c# tcp server client and I'm trying to connect them on my laptop and pc. The only way it will work is if I completely turn the firewall off so the server can listen. I have tried to add it as an exception but that wont work. the file path matches exact, I've tried adding it, then restarting the server and that won't work either. I don't want to have to turn off Win firewall everytime I want to run it, any help is appreciated. Code below is for the server and client if anyone is interested

Client:

```
TcpClient TCPClient;
TCPClient = new TcpClient("my ipv4", 629);
Console.WriteLine("connected");
```

Server:

```
TcpListener TCPServer;
TcpClient TCPClient;

TCPServer = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 629);
TCPServer.Start();
TCPClient = TCPServer.AcceptTcpClient();

    if (TCPClient.Connected)
    {
        //listen function to receives bytes
    }
}
```

Comment: please take screenshots of each tab of the firewall settings rule on the server you set up and add them to the question.

Comment: Do you *have* to use a port within the range of well-known port numbers? Maybe something in the range 49152–65535 would be better.

Comment: @Rachel check your antivirus' firewall as well

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look into what kind of code the firewall picks up, and modify it. I had this problem myself, and I just researched what kind of code the firewall picked up as malware, and did a slight modification of the code.
The firewall might see the TCP connection as a malicious backdoor, and block it.